# Get Specific value from API and store inside of variables (JavaScript)

Tags: json, api

I would like to get the specific value of "Subscribercount" from the following api using Javascript:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=UCJwchuXd_UWNxW-Z1Cg-liw&key=AIzaSyDUzfsMaYjn7dnGXy9ZEtQB_CuHyii4poc

and then I would like to store it inside of variables that are 2 digits, by this I mean, if the number is 3256, I would like to store: 32 in one variable and 56 in one variable.

I would be very glad if you could help.

Answer (score 0):

Get you api data, put them into a variable and run a while loop that removes two characters from the string using `str.substring()` and write those into a variable.

Example: Writing all split numbers in a "splitCount" array:

```
var splitCount = []; // This is the array in which we store our split numbers
//Getting api results via jQuery's GET request
$.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=UCJwchuXd_UWNxW-Z1Cg-liw&key=AIzaSyDUzfsMaYjn7dnGXy9ZEtQB_CuHyii4poc", function(result) {
    //result is our api answer and contains the recieved data
    //now we put the subscriber count into another variable (count); this is just for clarity
    count = result.items[0].statistics.subscriberCount;
    //While the subscriber count still has characters
    while (count.length) {
        splitCount.push(count.substr(0, 2)); //Push first two characters into the splitCount array from line 1
        count = count.substr(2); //Remove first two characters from the count string
    }       
    console.log(splitCount) //Output our splitCount array
});
```

Comment: How can I test this? and what will the variables be called where the numbers are stored? im really new to this btw

Comment: @Kenneth I've updated the comments in my code. In this case your numbers are stored in an array called `splitCount` (Line 1). You can test this by simply including jQuery in your HTML file and appending this code inside `<script></script>`-Tags

Comment: How would I make it so that instead of putting the first 2 characters in a array, put the last 2?

Comment: @Kenneth Use `count.substr(count.length - 2)` for putting the last two characters into the array

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=UCJwchuXd_UWNxW-Z1Cg-liw&key=AIzaSyDUzfsMaYjn7dnGXy9ZEtQB_CuHyii4poc",
            dataType: "json",
            complete: function(data){
                var response = data.responseJSON;
                var items = response.items;
                var item = items[0];
                var statistics = item.statistics;
                var subscriberCount = statistics.subscriberCount;
                console.log(subscriberCount);

            }
        });
    });
```

You can put all the variables on 1 line if you want.